# python request just open url, don't need show or open in browser

Tags: python

I make api call in another project, for example i got url `http://localhost:5000/api/test`. After i do this link on my browser, the file have updated.
But i need make it on my python bot calls. So i try to use request.

```
import requests
requests.get('http://localhost:5000/api/test')
```

But then file who are in `http://localhost:5000/api/test` was not updated.

I know its very complicated, but maybe anyone have idea? I don't need browser open i dont need any reaction, i just need with code open what url, and when correctly file will be updated.

UPDATED INFORMATION

then i click on browser the link `http://localhost:5000/api/test`
im getting `{"success": true}` and the file was updated with now data.

Then i try with my code im getting

```
    HTTP connection (1): localhost:5000 DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:5000 "GET /api/test HTTP/1.1" 302
 219 DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Resetting dropped connection: localhost DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:5000 "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 4470 200
```

But my file was not updated.

Comment: Try to add trailing `'/'` to your link

Comment: Put the result of `requests.get()` in a variable, then print it out various fields, like `r.status_code` and `r.text` to help diagnose what's happening?

Comment: What is the status code of the response? `response = request.get('http://localhost:5000/api/test')` and then `print(response.status_code)`

Comment: ```DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): localhost:5000
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:5000 "GET /api/test/ HTTP/1.1" 404 3342
404```

Comment: In addition to my previous comment about trailing slash. Seems like you're using *Django* and by default it appends slash to route *([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-APPEND_SLASH))*.

Comment: Im using it on microsoft teams bot, i need print link of file, what file formating then i get api call, so i need get latest date, so i need make request for update, and then print the link i try with ```http://localhost:5000/api/test/``` but its the same

Comment: @Kalakutas Ensure that your url is correct, you are getting a 404 error which means Page Not Found.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat without ```/``` im getting so in the first place my code was good DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new ```HTTP connection (1): localhost:5000
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:5000 "GET /api/test HTTP/1.1" 302 219
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Resetting dropped connection: localhost
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:http://localhost:5000 "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 4470
200``` but its not solve my problem i just back where i start

Comment: @Kalakutas, redirect to `/login` means that API you're trying to use requires authorization. Try to open this url in private tab.

Comment: @OlvinRoght it makes sense, but how to change for authorise, in api login with microsoft account

Comment: @Kalakutas What are the post parameters your login page expects? Edit your question with those details.

Comment: I fix what, thank you all for help